# fontawesome+jQuery: it doesn't change the "thumb down" icon to the "thumb up"

Tags: jquery, icons, font-awesome

the problem is that jQuery **does not change** the "thumb down" icon to the "thumb up"

I have tried to change other properties, like color, and even tried to change the "thumb down" icon to the "Github" icon - all these work well, but not "thumb up"

HTML

```
<button id="change_color">Change color</button>

<button id="change_to_github">Change to Github</button>

<button id="thumbs_up">Thumbs Up!</button><br><br>


<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-5x"></i><br><br><br><br>


<!-- Here it works well -->
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
```

jQuery

```
$("#change_color").click(function(){
    $(".fa-thumbs-o-down").toggleClass("red");
});

$("#change_to_github").click(function(){
    $(".fa-thumbs-o-down").toggleClass("fa-github");
});

$("#thumbs_up").click(function(){
    $(".fa-thumbs-o-down").toggleClass("fa-thumbs-o-up");
});
```

CSS

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

[here is my code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skparallax/n7wj2ggy/)

appreciate any help,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Doodlebunche's answer only works the first time is that you are using the original font awesome icon class name in the selector.  once you change that class the selector will fail.

In this situation I tend to use js specific classes to handle the js activities.  So I added the 'js-result' class in this version.  alternatively you could use an id.

Here's how I would write this:

```
<button id="change_color">Change color</button>
<button id="change_to_github">Change to Github</button>
<button id="thumbs_up">Thumbs Up!</button><br><br>
<i class="js-result fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-5x"></i><br><br><br><br>
<!-- Here it works well -->
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change_color").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".js-result").toggleClass("red");
    });

    $("#change_to_github").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".js-result").toggleClass("fa-github");
    });

    $("#thumbs_up").click(functione() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".js-result").toggleClass("fa-thumbs-o-up").toggleClass("fa-thumbs-o-down");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're toggling the class "fa-thumbs-o-up" which adds it, but doesn't remove the "fa-thumbs-o-down" class. If you remove the thumbs down class first, it works.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/n7wj2ggy/3/

```
$("#thumbs_up").click(function(){
    $(".fa-thumbs-o-down").removeClass("fa-thumbs-o-down").addClass("fa-thumbs-o-up");
});
```

Comment: it works, but one time. what if it is supposed to work every time, when the button "Thumbs Up!" is pressed. is there a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use callback function:

```
$("#thumbs_up").click(function(e){
    $(".fa-thumbs-o-down").toggleClass(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('fa-thumbs-o-down');
        return 'fa-thumbs-o-up';
    });
});
```

---

Small improvement

HTML

```
<button id="change_color" data-class="red">Change color</button>

<button id="change_to_github" data-class="fa-github">Change to Github</button>

<button id="thumbs_up" data-class="fa-thumbs-o-up">Thumbs Up!</button><br><br>


<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-5x"></i><br><br><br><br>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    var btn = $(this);
    $('.fa').toggleClass(function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
        return 'fa ' + btn.data('class') + ' fa-5x';
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ddp6ck5/1/)